# Issue with using Boto3 dynamodb conditions

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm trying to test out a put_item call with a condition expression and am getting an error when using Attr() from boto3.dynamodb.conditions. The error is

```
Invalid type for parameter ConditionExpression, value <boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Or object at 0x2044157a1>, type: <class 'boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Or'>. valid types: <class 'str'>
```

I'm using boto3 version 1.21.40. I have referenced the docs [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/conditions.html) but still can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr

client = boto3.client("dynamodb")

example = {
    "id": {"S": "12345"},
    "name": {"S": "foo"}
}

client.put_item(
    TableName="foo",
    Item=example,
    ReturnValues="NONE",
    ConditionExpression=(Attr("name").not_exists() | Attr("name").eq(example.get("name")))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions are using belong to the [Table client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/table/index.html), you are using the [low level client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#).

#### Table Client

ConditionExpression (condition from boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Attr method) –

The condition(s) an attribute(s) must meet. Valid conditions are listed in the DynamoDB Reference Guide.

#### Low level Client

ConditionExpression (string) –

A condition that must be satisfied in order for a conditional PutItem operation to succeed.

```
ConditionExpression="not_exists(#name) or #name = :name",
ExpressionAttributeNames={ "#name":"name"},
ExpressionAttributeValues={ ":name": example.get("name")}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html